# How to transform DCT block back to color values?

Tags: image-processing, colors, compression, jpeg, dct

So I am trying to use this 
https://www.nayuki.io/res/fast-discrete-cosine-transform-algorithms/NaiveDct.cs
in my image processing assignment, in which we are supposed to apply DCT on an a picture. *(8x8 block)*

```
static public double[,] Dct(double[,] array)
    {
        double[,] dct = new double[N, M];
        double factor = Math.PI / (N * M);
        //dct
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {                    
                double sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
                    {
                        sum += array[k, l] * Math.Cos((k * M + l + 0.5) * (i * M + j) * factor);
                    }
                }
                dct[i, j] = (int) sum;
            }
        }
        return dct;
    }
```

This is the method I use for the forward transformation.
Results on an 8x8 block look like this
[image]

But trying to restore the "color block" *(in this case it was used on the "blue" values of an rgb color)*.
With this code:

```
  static public double[,] inverseDct(double[,] array)
    {
        double[,] colorBlock = new double[N, M];
        double factor = Math.PI / (N * M);
        //dct
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {

                double sum = array[0, 0] / 2;

                for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
                {
                    int l = 0;
                    if (k == 0) l = 1;
                    for (; l < N; l++)
                    {
                        sum += array[k, l] * Math.Cos((k * M + l) * ((i * M + j) + 0.5) * factor);
                    }
                }
                colorBlock[i, j] = (int) sum;
            }
        }
        return colorBlock;
    }
```

It doesn't seem to work properly because the output of (the blue color value block in the picture above) now says this:
[image]

**I posted my entire code here:**
https://pastebin.com/XbCE3kBK

How do I get back my "***color***" values from the DCT Block? *(doing the reverse transformation?)*

Comment: The first algorithmic problem I noticed (did not look for others):
In forward DCT, a coefficient is the sum of each value, multiplied by a cosine factor.
In inverse DCT, you take one coefficient and add that, multiplied by a cosine factor, to each value.
Your "colorBlock" should be in the innermost loop.

Comment: Hint: `public static double[] InverseTransform(double[] vector)`: Computes the **unscaled** DCT type III on the specified array, returning a new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DCT(u,v)]   = [CC(i,j)] * EE{i=0..M-1;j=0..N-1} (             [INPUT(i,j)] * [cosinus1(u,v,i,j)] )
[INPUT(i,j)] =           * EE{u=0..M-1;v=0..N-1} ( [CC(u,v)] * [DCT(u,v)]   * [cosinus2(i,j,u,v)] )
    CC = (2/M)^0,5 * (2/N)^0,5 * C(i)*C(j) ~ (2/M)^0,5 * (2/N)^0,5 * C(u)*C(v)
    i=0 -> C(i)=1/2  |  i>0 ->; C(i)=1
    j=0 -> C(j)=1/2  |  j>0 -> C(j)=1  (i,j | u,v)
    [cosinus1(u,v,i,j)] = cos(PI/(2M)*(2i+1)*u) * cos(PI/(2N)*(2j+1)*v)
    [cosinus2(i,j,u,v)] = cos(PI/(2M)*(2u+1)*i) * cos(PI/(2N)*(2v+1)*j)

Constant CC (M = 8, N = 8)

    i=0, j=0 : CC(i,j) = (1/M)^0.5 * (1/M)^0.5 = 0,125
    i=0, j>0 : CC(i,j) = (1/M)^0.5 * (2/M)^0.5 = 0,177
    i>0, j=0 : CC(i,j) = (2/M)^0.5 * (1/M)^0.5 = 0,177
    i>0, j>0 : CC(i,j) = (2/M)^0.5 * (2/M)^0.5 = 0,25
```

See also:

- http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/DCT.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.